# What does <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> do in landscape mode on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, webkit, viewport

I'm trying to understand the scaling attributes on iOS.

1. According to [Apple's Developer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html), declaring `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` will tell iOS to scale a webpage to a 1:1 pixel ratio when the page loads (in portrait mode).
2. According to [a presentation](https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dkx3qtm_22dxsrgcf4) by the folks at HTML5Boilerplate (see slide 13), `device-width` will always correspond to the smaller measure of an iOS device's screen, regardless of the device's orientation.
3. Therefore, if you load a page in iOS with the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` declaration while holding the device in a landscape orientation, iOS will set the viewport's width according to what appears to be the screen's height, resulting in a 1.5:1 (iPhone 4s) or 2:1 (iPhone 5) pixel ratio.

Am I correct, or am I misunderstanding the definition of "width" and "device-width" as Apple uses them?

Furthermore, when an iOS device rotates, what does the viewport maintain?  It's width, or it's scale?  Does it depend on the meta settings?

Answer (score 5):

According to Apple's Developer Docs:

"Similarly, if you specify only the viewport width, the height and initial scale are inferred.  Notice that... the landscape orientation maintains a width equal to device-width, which changes the initial scale and has the effect of zooming in when the user changes to landscape orientation."

The article states that iOS keeps the same viewport setting regardless of orientation or rotating the device.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html), under "How Safari Infers the Width, Height, and Initial Scale".